# Identity with Lagrange polynomials.

Tags: calculus, analysis, numerical-methods

Let $x_0, x_1, \dots x_n$ be such that $x_i \ne x_j$ when $i \ne j$, we define
\begin{equation}
L_i(x) = \prod_{j \ne i} \frac{x - x_j}{x_i - x_j}.
\end{equation}

I want to prove that for each $1 \leq l \leq n,$
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} L_i(0)x_i^l = 0,
\end{equation}
in fact the above equality can be generalized to
\begin{equation} \tag{1}
\sum_{i=0}^{n} L_i(x)(x_i - x)^l = 0, \qquad 1 \le l \le n.
\end{equation}

We can rewrite $(1)$ as
\begin{align} 
\sum_{i=0}^{n} L_i(x)(x_i - x)^l &= \sum_{i=0}^{n} \Big( \prod_{j \ne j} \frac{x - x_j}{x_i - x_j} \Big)(x_i - x)^l \\ &= \prod_{k=0}^{n} (x - x_k) \sum_{i=0}^{n} \Big((x-x_i)^{l-1}\prod_{i \ne j} \frac{1}{x_i-x_j}\Big).
\end{align}

What remains is to prove that the sum $ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \Big((x-x_i)^{l-1}\prod_{i \ne j} \frac{1}{x_i-x_j}\Big)$ is equal to $0$ for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I believe that it can be done by adding term by term and some simple manipulations, but is there any smarter method to prove such equality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lagrange or Newton interpolation over $n+1$ nodes of a polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ or lower just replicates that polynomial $p$, $L[p]=p$ where $L$ is the operator transforming a polynomial into its interpolation polynomial with the given data. So evaluating at a root of the polynomial $p$ will give the value zero either way.

Thus if $p(t)=(t-x)^l$, $l\le n$, then $p(t)=L[p](t)$ and $L[p](x)=p(x)=(x-x)^l=0$.

Comment: What polynomial are you ending up interpolating here exactly?

Comment: I figured it out. The issue in the OP is the generalization...the original is easier to prove. I'm not certain the generalization is even true.

Comment: $p_x(t)=(t-x)^l$ is a polynomial of degree $l\le n$ in $t$, $p_x(x)=0$.

Comment: Is that what is implemented by OP's generalization? It seems like it is slightly different since in the OP the polynomial being examined has degree $n+l$. I think you want more like $L_i(x)(x_i-y_0)^l$, that is 0 at $x=y_0$, now replace $y_0$ as you want.

Comment: Start with $\sum_{i=0}^nL_i(t)(x_i-x)^l=\sum_{i=0}^nL_i(t)p(x_i)=p(t)=(t-x)^l$ and then set $t=x$.

Comment: I see, thanks. I don't like having this intermediate step with a polynomial of degree $n+l$ but it makes sense now.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could You give some more hints for generalized part?

Comment: @Interpolated : What generalized part? My whole answer is about an even more generalized case, using a general polynomial instead of the special $(t-x)^l$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann After while of thinking I get it, thank You